# Concatenating previous line with current line based on condition

Tags: awk, concatenation, conditional-statements, lines

I need help scripting the following. If the current Line starts with `#STOP#` and the previous line also starts with `"#STOP#"` then simply print the line.
If current Line starts with `"#STOP#"` and previous line also starts with `"MSG#"` concatenate previous line to current line.

Input file:

```
#STOP# |package1| function1
#STOP# |package2|   function2
#MSG#  |package3| SQL1
#STOP# |package4|  MapperBean
#MSG#  |package3|  SQL2
#STOP# |package4|  MapperBean
#STOP# |package4|   MapperBean
#STOP# |package5|  ActionItem
```

Desired output:

```
#STOP# |package1| function1
#STOP# |package2|   function2
#STOP# |package4|  MapperBean  #MSG#  |package3| SQL1
#STOP# |package4|  MapperBean  #MSG#  |package3|  SQL2
#STOP# |package4|   MapperBean
#STOP# |package5|  ActionItem
```

Answer (score 4):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1=="#MSG#"{msg=OFS $0;next}{print $0(msg?msg:"");msg=""}' file
#STOP# |package1| function1 
#STOP# |package2|   function2 
#STOP# |package4|  MapperBean #MSG#  |package3| SQL1
#STOP# |package4|  MapperBean #MSG#  |package3|  SQL2
#STOP# |package4|   MapperBean 
#STOP# |package5|  ActionItem
```

Comment: You can remove the parentheses, but it may be some less readable. `{print $0,msg?msg:"";msg=""}`

Comment: @Jotne statement then becomes ambiguous... `Gawk` will be okay, `BSD awk` will complain. Safer and more readable with, zero benefit without.

Comment: I guess the ternary isn't strictly required anyway, golfing you could go for something like `awk '/^#MSG#/{m=$0;next}{print $0,m;m=""}' file` shorted yet would be a `sed` solution.

Comment: @sudo_O: That's a nice simplification, but, as in your answer, you'll end up appending a lone space char. at the end of unconcatenated lines due to using `,` with `print`. Thus, you'll probably want `print $0 (m ? " "m : "");m=""`