# Wrap indented lines back to previous line

Tags: bash, macos, powershell, shell

I want to turn the following input:

```
May 13 00:29:49 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[12610]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

into the following output:

```
May 13 00:29:49 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[12610]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

That is, the indented lines should be joined to the preceding non-indented line.

I already have a PowerShell solution, but now I need a solution using *native* macOS utilities, such as a `bash` solution.

Here is the PowerShell solution, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69035556/45375) to my previous question:

```
  $mergedLine = ''
  switch -Regex -File file.log {
    '^\S' {  # 'May ...' line, no leading whitespace.
      if ($mergedLine) { $mergedLine } # output previous 
      $mergedLine = $_
    }
    default { # Subsequent, indented line (leading whitespace)
      $mergedLine += ' ' + $_.TrimStart()
    }
  }
  $mergedLine # output final merged line
```

Here is my attempt at converting this to a `bash` script:

```
file=/xx
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=
while read -r line
do
case $line in
        [a-zA-Z]*)
        if [ $line ];then
        line=$line
        fi
        y=$line
        ;;
        *)
        line=$y$line
        ;;
esac
echo $line
done <$file
IFS=$OIFS
```

Unfortunately, it isn't working as intended, because I receive the following output:

```
May 13 00:29:49 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.bundles[12610]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice: Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice: Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

Comment: Good hear. Fyi: PowerShell (Core) also [runs on a mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos)

Comment: @iRon  I know it can. but I still need the bash/shell. And if u may, please undo your vote to this question. thank you.

Comment: A comment on the PowerShell version: you use the .Net class `System.IO.StreamReader` (rather then the native `Get-Content` cmdlet) probably for [performance reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations) but simular to [building object collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026), strings are immutable and therefore the increase assignment operator (`+=`) might become pretty expensive. Instead, you better drop each line on the pipeline and `-Join` them in once.

Comment: @iRon   Yes, because of performance.  the file is too huge. thank you for your both advice. I will learn how to ask a great question as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367445/concatenating-previous-line-with-current-line-based-on-condition

Answer (score 1):

- In the realm of Unix utilities, **[`awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) has fundamental conceptual similarities to PowerShell's [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement**<sup>[1]</sup>, which the PowerShell solution is based on.
- As an external, compiled utility, **`awk` far outperforms any solution written in pure (`bash`) shell code**, such as the `while` / `case` loop-based solution you tried in your question.

The equivalent (portable) `awk` solution is:

```sh
awk '
  /^[^[:blank:]]/ {                   # line starts with non-whitespace char.
    if (length(mergedLines)>0) { print mergedLines } # print previous merged line
    mergedLines = $0                  # start new merged line
    next 
  }
  {                                   # indented line
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "")          # trim leading whitespace
    mergedLines = mergedLines " " $0  # join to previous lines
  }
  END { 
    print mergedLines                 # print last merged line
  }
' file.log
```

Note that **the `awk` version that comes with macOS is mostly limited to POSIX-mandated features**, whereas **[*GNU* Awk (`gawk`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) - installable on demand on Macs - offers many additional features**, such as convenient character-class shortcuts `\S` and `\s` in lieu of `^[:blank:]` and `[:blank:]` (though, technically, the strict equivalents are `^[:space:]` and `[:space:]`, but *intra*-line that doesn't make a difference), as also available in the .NET regex implementation that PowerShell utilizes.

[tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) suggests the following streamlined, more `awk`-idiomatic variant:

```sh
awk '
  /^[[:blank:]]/ {           # indented line
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]/, "")  # trim leading whitespace
    merged = merged " " $0   # join to previous lines
    next
  }
  merged {                   # previous merged line exists?
    print merged             # print previous
  }
  {                          # line starts with non-whitespace char.
    merged = $0              # start new merged line  
  }
  END {
    print merged             # print last merged line
  }
' file.log
```

---

<sup>[1] In fact, the much older `awk` *inspired* PowerShell's `switch` statement.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that applies minimal modifications to your script to get it working correctly. However, I would recommend using @mklement0's awk based solution ahead of this one.

```sh
file=/xx
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=
while read -r line
do
    case $line in
        [a-zA-Z]*)
        if [ "$formatted_line" ];then
            echo "$formatted_line"
        fi
        formatted_line="$line"
        ;;
        *)
        formatted_line="$formatted_line $line"
        ;;
    esac
done <$file
if [ "$formatted_line" ];then
    echo "$formatted_line"
fi
IFS=$OIFS
```